# Prove that $\{x^n\}$ is convergent to $x\notin S\subseteq \ell_\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

As a follow-up to my previous post [Prove that $\{x^n\}$ is Cauchy in $S\subseteq \ell_\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037822/prove-that-xn-is-cauchy-in-s-subseteq-ell-infty). I would like to ask the following question. Let $S$ be the set of sequences having only a finite number of non-zero terms. Clearly, $S\subseteq \ell_\infty$. Take $\{x^n\}$ in $S$ where $x^n=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,\cdots).$ I want to prove that $\{x^n\}$ is convergent to $x=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots)\notin S\subseteq \ell_\infty.$

**MY TRIAL**

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and $n\in \Bbb{N}.$ Then,
\begin{align}\Vert x^n-x\Vert_ {\infty}=\sup\limits_{n\in \Bbb{N}}\left|\frac{1}{n}-0 \right|\end{align}
By convergence of $\{1/n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ to $0$, there exists $N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that 
\begin{align}\Vert x^n-x\Vert_ {\infty}=\sup\limits_{n\in \Bbb{N}}\left|\frac{1}{n}-0\right|=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon,\;\;\forall\; n\geq N. \end{align}

I think I'm wrong but please, can you help? I'm new into Functional analysis. Thanks

Comment: You forgot the $\forall \epsilon > 0$ before $\exists N$, I think? Otherwise it looks correct. :)

Comment: The sequence $x$ is not an element of $S$.

Comment: @ Roberto Rastapopoulos: Oh, sorry! I'll edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *idea* is just fine, but you are not expressing it properly. You should say that, since $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$, then, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a natural $N$ such that $n\geqslant N\implies\frac1n<\varepsilon$ (actually, this is what it *means* to assert that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$) and so$$n\geqslant N\implies\lVert x-x^n\rVert_\infty=\sup\left\{0,\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+2},\ldots\right\}=\frac1{n+1}<\varepsilon.$$However, $x\notin S$. So, this proves that in $S$ your sequence diverges.

Comment: My question is $S$ is not complete but why should it converge to a point in $S$?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Please read the two sentences that I've added to my answer.

Comment: Before I accept this answer, can you please, show me explicitly what $\Vert x-x^\Vert _\infty$ looks like? Just like you did before!

Comment: It is done now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am very grateful!

Comment: Can you please explain to me why $x\notin S?$

Comment: Because, by definition, the elements of $S$ have only finitely many non-zero terms, whereas $x$ has infinitely many non-zero terms (actually, **all** of its terms are non-zero).

Comment: I really appreciate that! Thanks once again!